# Chrome extension - pass function result from content script to popup.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have extension with popup.html which has popup.js in it.
I use popup.js to call function located in content script using chrome.tabs.sendMessage -method.
This is working nicely, but..

How do I return the value of the function back to popup.js ? Do I need to set up a listener on the popup.js aswell or what ?

On my popup.js I have:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
 expiryRequest: 'expiry '
}, function (response) {
if (response.refreshResponse === true) {
 console.log('Expiry taken');
} else {
 console.log('Expiry NOT taken');
}
});
```

This part works great..

On my content script I read certain div into a vartiable "result".
At the end of the function on content script I have used.

```
return result;
```

or

```
return true;
```

None of those returns anything back tuo popup.js.
What do I need to change in order to get my return to work from content script to popup.js ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not `return` your result, but send it back.

[`chrome.runtime.onMessage` callbacks](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) take 3 parameters: the message, the sender information, and the sendResponse callback.

To pass a response back, `sendResponse` must be called:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
  if(message.ping) sendResponse({pong: true});
});
```

However, there's an additional trick to it. The event listener should either reply immediately (i.e. synchronously, before it exits) or signal that it will reply later. This is done with the return value:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
  if(message.ping) {
    chrome.storage.local.get("shouldReply", function(result){
      // This is asynchronous: by now the listener returned
      if(result.shouldReply) sendResponse({pong: true});
    });
  }
  return true; // Indicate that you will eventually call sendResponse
});
```

Unless you do this, `sendResponse` reference is invalidated when the listener exits and an undefined response is sent.

One more caveat: you should call `sendResponse` no more than once; it will generate an error otherwise.

Comment: Thank you fro you fast enswer but Im still confused.. If I want to send back the content of the variable "result" how do I do it ?

sendResponse({result: true});

Comment: Message can be anything. You could simply return the variable itself: `sendResponse(result)`, or you can wrap it in an object: `sendResponse({refreshResponse: result})` (that would match your other code)

Comment: Thank you so much @Xan. This was the answer I was looking for, especially the last part about returning true. I had a lot of confusion on why my listener was returning early, but thanks to your answer, it is clear now :)

Comment: Oh, that was interesting and helpful. Thanks :)